# How to return an Integral in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to figure out Haskell, but I'm a bit stuck with 'Integral'.
From what I gather, Int and Integer are both Integral.
However if I try to compile a function like this:

```
lastNums :: Integral a => a -> a
lastNums a = read ( tail ( show a ) ) :: Integer
```

I get

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Integer)
from the context (Integral a)
```

How do I return an Integral?

Also lets say I have to stick to that function signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's read this function type signature in English.

```
lastNums :: Integral a => a -> a
```

This means that "Let the caller choose any integral type.  The lastNums function can take a value of that type and produce another value of the same type."

However, your definition always returns `Integer`.  According to the type signature, it's *supposed* to leave that decision up to the caller.

Easiest way to fix this:

```
lastNums :: Integer -> Integer
lastNums = read . tail . show
```

There's no shame in defining a monomorphic function.  Don't feel it has to be polymorphic just because it *can* be polymorphic.  Often the polymorphic version is more complicated.

Here's another way:

```
lastNums :: (Integral a, Num a) => a -> a
lastNums = fromInteger . read . tail . show . toInteger
```

And another way:

```
lastNums :: (Integral a, Read a, Show a) => a -> a
lastNums = read . tail . show
```

Comment: Another way of reading the signature in English, same as this answer but with a slightly different emphasis: for any `Integral` type `a` **that the caller chooses**, this function accepts and returns **that exact same type**. This "caller choice" dynamic can be very useful for understanding this sort of situation.  The problem with OP's function then is that the caller may have chosen some other `Integral` type that's not `Integer`.

Comment: @dfeuer: `fromInteger` is part of `Num`, last time I checked.

Comment: @LuisCasillas: That's a good way of phrasing it.  I've integrated that into the answer.

Comment: Yes, but `Integral` is a subclass of `Real` (itself a subclass of `Num` and `Ord`), as well as `Enum`.

Answer (score 1):

While `Int` and `Integer` both implement `Integral`, Haskell doesn't quite work like that.  Instead, if your function returns a value of type `Integral a => a`, then it must be able to return *any* value that implements the `Integral` typeclass.  This is different from how most OOP languages use interfaces, in which you can return a specific instance of an interface by casting it to the interface type.

In this case, if you wanted a function `lastNums` to take an `Integral` value, convert it to a string, drop the first digits, then convert back to an `Integral` value, you would have to implement it as

```
lastNums :: (Integral a, Show a, Read a) => a -> a
lastNums a = read ( tail ( show a ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to Read and Show also. And get rid of the Integer annotation. An Integer is a concrete type while Integral is a typeclass.

```
lastNums :: (Integral a, Show a, Integral b, Read b) => a -> b
lastNums = read . tail . show 

*Main> lastNums (32 :: Int) :: Integer
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Integral` class offers integer division, and it's a subclass of `Ord`, so it has comparison too. Thus we can skip the string and just do math. Warning: I haven't tested this yet.

```
lastNums x | x < 0 = -x
           | otherwise = dropBiggest x

dropBiggest x = db x 0 1

db x acc !val
  | x < 10 = acc
  | otherwise = case x `quotRem` 10 of
                  (q, r) -> db q (acc + r * val) (val * 10)
```

Side notes: the bang pattern serves to make `db` unconditionally strict in `val`. We could add one to `acc` as well, but GHC will almost certainly figure that out on its own. Last I checked, GHC's native code generator (the default back-end) is not so great at optimizing division by known divisors. The LLVM back-end is much better at that.