# Why does returning a String not count as an expression of type Show x?

Tags: haskell

Can anyone help me understand why this code produces a compilation error?

```
hello :: (Show x) => x
hello = "Hello"
```

I thought `String` had the properties of `Show`, so the function should be able to return a `String`? Here is the error message:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘x’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
  ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      hello :: forall x. Show x => x
    at script.hs:160:1-25
• In the expression: "Hello"
  In an equation for ‘hello’: hello = "Hello"
• Relevant bindings include
    hello :: x (bound at script.hs:161:1)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Print out the message? Cast the string to any `Show` type? Cast any `Show` type to a string?

Comment: `"Hello"` is a *string*. By using a signature `Show x => x`, you promise that for *any* `x` that is a member of the `Show` typeclass, your function will produce a value, but that promise does not hold, since you only do this if `x ~ String`.

Comment: See also [Why can a Num act like a Fractional?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42820603/791604).

Comment: @Aplet123 I was just playing around with generic type signatures, I wasn't trying to cast anything. My only goal was to get it to compile :) But I misunderstood what generic types signatures actually mean in Haskell. It's cleared up now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your type signature doesn't mean what you think it means.

From your explanation it seems that you read this signature something like "*I'm going to return you a value of some type `x` that has an instance of `Show`. I'm not going to tell you what type it will be exactly, but I promise it will have an instance of `Show`*"

But what it really means is "*pick a type, any type, just make sure it has an instance of `Show`, and I promise I will return you a value of that type*"

In other words, when a function is generic, it's the *caller* of the function who chooses what the generic type will be, not the implementer.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I was conflating the concept of Haskell type classes with interfaces from imperative languages like Java

Comment: Well, type classes actually _are_ very much like interfaces in Java, especially in this particular case where the type class has a single parameter. Your function would be roughly equivalent to something like `X hello<X extends IShow>()` in Java.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin they're not the same in this case, actually. Java doesn't support return type polymorphism except as the OP understood it.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()) an example of return type-polymorphic method @is7s?

Comment: I didn't say Java does not support return type polymorphism at all. I said it only supports it in the way the OP understood it. In the example you linked to, `emptyList()` will always return a concrete value and does not depend on the context. Which is equivalent to the 1st definition in your answer. And is not equivalent to how return type polymorphism works in type classes.

Comment: Actually, `emptyList()` will return a value of type that _the caller chooses_. I mean, it will be wrapped in `List<>`, but the element of the list, which is the generic parameter of the function, is chosen by the caller. `emptyList` itself doesn't choose its generic parameter, the caller does. This is equivalent to my second definition, not first.

Comment: In my comment, I said `emptyList()` will always return a _concrete value_ and not a _concrete type_. Which is still not how type classes operate and still equivalent to your 1st definition :)

Comment: That only means that Java doesn't have type classes - i.e. different behavior depending on types. But it still has parametric polymorphism, including in return type. And it's the exact same as in Haskell. Compare Java's `emptyList()` to `emptyList :: [a]; emptyList = []`

Comment: I think we are in agreement here. One of the main differences between OOP interfaces and type classes is how they behave with return type polymorphism. And the reason why I started this was your statement above _"type classes actually are very much like interfaces in Java, especially in this particular case where the type class has a single parameter"_, which is not accurate. And I also never stated that Java does not support parametric polymorphism. Cheers.

Comment: The difference between return types in Haskell and most OOP languages is also nicely explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33702641/9992041) to a similar question